# Making the latest build to be made available in appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have got 10 versions of my app in the test flight. 
Few days back I submitted my app for review. I expected that the latest build will be reviewed and will be ready for sale. But the build that I uploaded the first time has been made as the ready for sale where as the latest build is not available for sale. How can I specify that the latest build thats in test flight to be made available in app store instead of the first build that i have uploaded?

Comment: was the first build the latest one at the time of submitting it for review?

Comment: what you have written the version number?

Comment: Yes the first build was marked as latest one while submissal

Comment: How can I be able to choose the build?

Comment: I tried https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW9

Comment: But the plus symbol thats nearby the word build is not showing up

Comment: they can only submit to the app store the version you submitted for review, if you add new builds after that, it will have to go to review, you cant submit a build and then change the code without it going for review again

Comment: Can you please explain further?

Comment: basically, whatever you submit for review is what goes to the app store, doesnt matter if you add builds afterwards. you should only submit for review when you are 100% certain your app is ready for the app store, not just any random build.

Comment: ok thank you... How can i be able to choose the specific build and submit it for review..

Comment: point 4 in that link you added in the comments above should cover that

Comment: but im not able to choose the build using the link... the plus symbol is not at all visible.. should I upload a new build and try?

Comment: should I upload new build bro to different version and submit it for review bro?